# UITableview create alphabetic indexing from data array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have a NSMutableArray which is populated by a sqlite query which returns everything I want to display in my UITableview in alphabetical order.

I know want to display the letter indexs like you see in the contacts application etc.

However I am not sure how to set up the indexs and create the sections from this array so that each sections is the next letter in the alphabet.

How would I go about taking my array and getting the sections and indexs needed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is addressed in Apple documentation.

Comment: @PeterDeWeese can you send a link? I was unable to find anything on the topic

Comment: Here is a tutorial: http://www.iphonedevcentral.com/indexed-uitableview-tutorial/ Here is the Apple Doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Also check the docs or header for UITableViewDataSource, especially `- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView;                                                    // return list of section titles to display in section index view (e.g. "ABCD...Z#")`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your array (NSMutableArray myArray) with letters looks something like this:

```
(
    {
    headerTitle = V;
    rowValues =         (
                    {
            id = 60;
            name = "Valley of the Giants (2)";
            "real_name" = "Valley of the Giants";
            "wine_count" = " (2)";
        }
    );
},
    {
    headerTitle = R;
    rowValues =         (
                    {
            id = 47;
            name = "Rothbury Estate (6)";
            "real_name" = "Rothbury Estate";
            "wine_count" = " (6)";
        },
                    {
            id = 48;
            name = "Rouge Homme (4)";
            "real_name" = "Rouge Homme";
        },
                    {
            id = 45;
            name = "Rawson\U2019s Retreat (7)";
            "real_name" = "Rawson\U2019s Retreat";
        },
                    {
            id = 46;
            name = "Rosemount Estate (36)";
            "real_name" = "Rosemount Estate";
        }
    );
},
```

in a table view, set number of sections

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [myArray count];
}
```

Number of rows in a section:

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[[myArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"rowValues"] count];
}
```

Section title

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[myArray objectAtIndex:section] valueForKey:@"headerTitle"];
}
```

Then inside cellForRowAtIndexPath you can access your information something like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *name= [[[[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"rowValues"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];

    // And create your cell like you usually do...
}
```

If you need to sort array in alphabetical order you can do it like:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"headerTitle" ascending:YES];
[myArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```